# Deleting shared object across map and unordered map

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

I declare both an unordered map: `std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<T>> orderMap`
and a (ordered) map `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<T>> orderBook` .

Both the map and unordered map share the same values (pointers to the respective objects).
E.g.

```
int key = 5;
std::unique_ptr<T> value(new T(args));
orderMap.insert(std::make_pair(key, std::move(value)));
orderBook.insert(std::make_pair(key, std::move(value)));
```

As the unordered_map allows for O(1) access to an element, I will update the underlying object T by using unordered_map (instead of traversing through the map to find the element).

**Question**

1. If I were to access an appropriate pointer using the unordered map and proceed to delete/free the pointer (thereby removing the underlying object from the heap), what would be the consequence to the (ordered) map? Would the map dynamically call erase on the same pointer or is the behavior undefined ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your two `insert` calls shouldn't compile, as `unique_ptr` is not copyable. Show your actual code, preferably a [mcve]. There ain't no way you can have two instances of `std::unique_ptr` manage the same raw pointer on the heap, without invoking undefined behavior somewhere.

Comment: ... so use `std::shared_ptr` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Both the map and unordered map share the same values (pointers to the respective objects).

They really, **really** shouldn't. Unique pointers own the object that they point at. And that ownership is **unique** as the name implies. Having multiple unique pointers to the same object contradicts this uniqueness. This is a broken design.

> ```
> std::unique_ptr<T> value(new T(args));
> orderMap.insert(key, value);
> orderBook.insert(key, value);
> ```

This example is ill-formed because `insert` copies the argument and `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable.

> what would be the consequence to the (ordered) map?

The pointer in the map that pointed to the object becomes invalid. When that unique pointer is destroyed, it will proceed to delete the invalid pointer. The behaviour of that is undefined. Undefined behaviour should be avoided.

---

If you need *shared* ownership, then you might want to use a *shared pointer* instead.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking to delete an object from the map without incurring the O(log N) time. Using a shared pointer would not be able to dynamically erase the pointer from the map when I erase it from the unordered map, right? I guess I am forced to incur the O(log N) cost when erasing an element from a map.